# Enviar mensaje por socket por bloques en C

Tags: c, windows, socket

Necesito enviar paquetes de datos por bloques a través de un `socket`. Yo tengo un puntero de tipo `uchar` con el mensaje completo, y una variable de tipo `int` con la longitud del mismo.

La conexión del `socket` ya la tengo hecha perfectamente, solo necesito una ayuda de como lograr ir enviando el mensaje por bloques de 1024 ya que estuve probando con varios ejemplos y con ninguno pude conseguirlo.

Algo así es lo que intento resolver:

```
BOOL enviarMensaje( UCHAR *sSndData, UINT16 ulSndDataLen)
{

   #define SEND_MAX_SIZE       1024   
   int handle=-1;
   short retVal =-1 ;
   int totalEnviados=0;

   handle=CrearSocket(sTCPAddress,ulTCPPort);
   timeout.tv_sec = 2; //segundos
   timeout.tv_usec = 100; //microsegundos
   setsockopt(handle,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&timeout,sizeof(timeout));

   timeout.tv_sec = 2;
   timeout.tv_usec = 100;
   setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET,SO_PKTRCVTIMEO,(char*)&timeout,sizeof(timeout));   

   if(handle >=0)
   {
      while(totalEnviados<ulSndDataLen){
         retVal = send(handle,sSndData,SEND_MAX_SIZE,0);
         totalEnviados+= retVal;
       }
       closesocket(handle);
   }
}
```

Comment: Revisa el valor de retVal para saber si está reportando un error el sistema operativo. Si retVal es -1 puedes revisar el valor que tenga la variable errno para saber que error está ocurriendo